# Does anyone know the name of this curve?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, terminology, plane-curves

I have come upon
the curve with the following parametric equations:

$$x(t)=\log(2+2\cos(t))/2$$ 
$$y(t)=t/2$$

for $-\pi<t<\pi$. It gives the image in the complex plane under $\log(1+z)$ of the unit circle. Does anyone know whether it has a name? It seems like this must have been studied at some point before.

Greg

Comment: For a non-parametric form, observe $x = \log(2+2\cos t)/2=\log(4 \cos^2(t/2))/2=\log|2\cos y|$. The bounds on $t$ make $\cos y$ non-negative, so that we can drop the absolute value, and we can go on to write $e^x = 2\cos y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more or less a reflected and shifted version of the so-called ["catenary of equal resistance"](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/chainettedegaleresistance/chainettedegaleresistance.shtml) (*en français*, sorry). [Here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AMPA/AMPA_1826-1827__17_/AMPA_1826-1827__17__59_1/AMPA_1826-1827__17__59_1.pdf) is the paper where they were first studied.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Equal_resistance_catenary) gives a derivation for the equation of the catenary of equal resistance; in some references, this is also called the "catenary of uniform strength". See [this](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.chmm/1263838627) for instance.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious to how you found/knew this answer.

Comment: @Willie: I will admit to spending (wasting?) the better part of my teenage years studying plane curves (mucking around in BASIC/Logo, scrounging books, etc.)... :) ...so yes, I still have those names from memory. I only went to that French site to check if my memory was correct.